# How can I verify that my buildah container image was actually created in my Tekton Task

Tags: docker, kubernetes, tekton, tekton-pipelines, buildah

I'm working on creating a Tekton pipeline on my Kind cluster. I have a `Task` where the first `step` builds a container image using buildah. And now I want to verify that the container image was actually created.

So in the next `step`, I try to "view" my container image (with `ls`). I've mounted an `emptyDir` volume to the `Task`, and my mount path is `/var/lib/containers` (where buildah puts its artifacts by default). I have tried doing an `ls /var/lib/containers` in a following `step`, but I get a `no such file or directory` response. I guess this is because the second `step` is happening in a new container? But I thought that the volume existed in all my containers for this specific `Task`. I'm not very educated on how this works, as you can see.

So is there any good way to verify that my container image was actually created? Can I for instance stop the pod from terminating after the `Task` is finished, so that I can shell into the container and browse the file system or something?

Here is the `Task` definition:

```
---
apiVersion: tekton.dev/v1beta1
kind: Task
metadata:
  name: build-and-deploy
spec:
  params:
    - name: contextDir
      default: .
    - name: destinationImage
      default: "$(outputs.resources.app-image.url)"
    - name: dockerFile
      default: Dockerfile
  resources:
    inputs:
      - name: repo
        type: git
    outputs:
      - name: app-image
        type: image
  steps:
    - name: build-image
      image: quay.io/buildah/stable
      workingDir: "/workspace/repo/$(inputs.params.contextDir)"
      command: ["buildah", "bud", "--layers", "-f", "$(inputs.params.dockerFile)", "-t", "$(inputs.params.destinationImage)", "."]
      volumeMounts:
        - name: varlibcontainers
          mountPath: /var/lib/containers
      securityContext:
        privileged: true
        runAsUser: 0
  volumes:
    - name: varlibcontainers
      emptyDir: {}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So is there any good way to verify that my container image was actually created?

You seem to have created a custom Buildah-task. I would recommend to use the [Buildah-task from Tekton Catalog](https://github.com/tektoncd/catalog/tree/master/task/buildah/0.2), or at least use it as **inspiration**.

The Buildah-task in the catalog use a *digestfile* that is written by buildah when pushed (I guess you want to push it so that you can deploy it?) and then the Task has a [Task Result](https://github.com/tektoncd/pipeline/blob/master/docs/tasks.md#emitting-results) that [returns the image digest](https://github.com/tektoncd/catalog/blob/master/task/buildah/0.2/buildah.yaml#L54) - if any step fails that step is shown as failed and you can see it in e.g. a Dashboard or using the cli client.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What do you mean by a "custom Buildah-task"? I'm new to Tekton (and cloud native & CI/CD in general), and I've been using the Red Hat Tekton tutorial for inspiration (https://github.com/redhat-scholars/tekton-tutorial/blob/master/tasks/build-app-task.yaml#L48). That's where I got the buildah command from. I've also seen this exact command and it's arguments been used in other Tekton examples.

Comment: Ah, right. But using a task-result with image-digest as in the task I linked, is a good way to see that an image is built. If it fits your context, it is good to use the tasks from Tekton Catalog since they are maintained. OpenShift Pipelines also has tasks, sometimes they are a bit old. The `resources: input and output`-part is often replaced with `workspaces` now.

Comment: Thanks, I'll definitely check this out.